# The EventListener I put on my buttons does not work on the first click

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling, dom-events

The only problem I have with this code is that it won't start incrementing my numbers when I click on the "Player One" button or on the "Player Two" button. Everything else works it's just that I have to click twice to have it start incrementing. Is there a way I could just have it do that from the first click?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Score Keeper</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span id="player1Score">0</span> to <span id="player2Score">0</span></h1>
    <p>Playing to: <span id="matchScore">5</span></p>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="matchScore">
        <button>Player One</button>
        <button>Player Two</button>
        <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var player1Score = 0
    var player2Score = 0
    var buttP1 = document.querySelector("button")
    var buttP2 = document.querySelectorAll("button")[1]
    var buttReset = document.querySelectorAll("button")[2]
    var inputMatchScore = document.querySelector("input")

    buttP1.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent < Number(document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent)){
            document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent = player1Score++
        }
    })
    buttP2.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent < Number(document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent)){
            document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent = player2Score++
        }
    })
    buttReset.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent = 0
        document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent = 0
        player1Score = 0
        player2Score = 0
    })
    inputMatchScore.addEventListener("input", function(){
        document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent = document.querySelector("input").value
    })
}, 500);
```

Comment: In addition to the main problem [PM 77-1 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58959531/157247), there's also no reason to use `setTimeout` in your code. Move your `script` tag to the end of the `body`, just prior to the `</body>` tag, and just use the body of your timer function directly. (On even vaguely modern browsers you could add `defer` to your `script` tag instead.) Also, there's no reason to repeatedly ask the DOM for the same information; instead, `var list = document.querySelectorAll("button")` (you could also use `getElementsByTagName`) and then use that list to set up your vars.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the way you programmed it.

```
 document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent = player1Score++
```

Specifically, `player1Score++` part.  It means that 1st the ***current value*** is used in the expression (in your case, direct assignment) and only then it's incremented.

`++player1Score` will work for you.

One of the tutorials on the topic:  https://www.tutorialgateway.org/increment-and-decrement-operators-in-javascript/

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Replaced.  Thank you. Since I decided not to use `postfix` and `prefix` terminology in my short answer - needed a tutorial for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer you increment directly.

```js
window.setTimeout(function() {
    var player1Score = 0
    var player2Score = 0
    var buttP1 = document.querySelector("button")
    var buttP2 = document.querySelectorAll("button")[1]
    var buttReset = document.querySelectorAll("button")[2]
    var inputMatchScore = document.querySelector("input")

    buttP1.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent < Number(document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent)){
          document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent++
        }
    })
    buttP2.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent < Number(document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent)){
            document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent++
        }
    })
    buttReset.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent = 0
        document.getElementById("player2Score").textContent = 0
        player1Score = 0
        player2Score = 0
    })
    inputMatchScore.addEventListener("input", function(){
        document.getElementById("matchScore").textContent = document.querySelector("input").value
    })
}, 500);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Score Keeper</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><span id="player1Score">0</span> to <span id="player2Score">0</span></h1>
    <p>Playing to: <span id="matchScore">5</span></p>
    <div>
        <input type="number" name="matchScore">
        <button>Player One</button>
        <button>Player Two</button>
        <button>Reset</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
 document.getElementById("player1Score").textContent++
```